# Getting error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'

Tags: python

In jupitar notebooks..
I created a module by the name my_module

When Im trying to import this module im getting an error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'

Any idea how to fix this one.

Please help

sys.path ==>
[
'/Users/frh/Documents/PYTHON3/Corey_schafer', '/Users/frh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/Users/frh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/Users/frh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '', 
'/Users/frh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/Users/frh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa', '/Users/frh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions', 
'/Users/frh/.ipython'
]

sys.executable
'/Users/frh/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3'

import sys
sys.version
'3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 13:42:34) \n[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]'

## From terminal

python --version
Python 3.7.6

Comment: I think you should provide a full path for your module or have it in the same folder where your current module/file is, or your module should be in one of the paths where sys module is looking for

Comment: @apet Im having the my_module in the same directory

Comment: try 'import .my_module', or full path

Comment: Can you post the code that throws the error?

Comment: `import my_module as mmt`


`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-c30f53834505> in <module>
----> 1 import my_module as mmt
      2 
      3 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'`

Answer (score 1):

if you observe jupyter notebook saved with the extension .ipynb .

Definition of Module:Any code written in python and saved with extension .py is known as module.

So you have to first convert .ipynb >>>.py then you can easily import.

how we convert [link here](https://medium.com/@erdmyzn/convert-jupyter-ipynb-to-python-py-and-python-py-to-file-exe-265329d9be95)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.... thats what i was using as a workaround,...what i did was...i opened the terminal and created a .py file and started to import it...

Comment: you save one python code with .py extension and place in that folder where yur file kept then import filename. that work for me